# Where to start with P190s Seismic Navigation Files?

Tags: geophysics, oceanography, seismic, data-formats

I have a few P190s navigation files from a 2D reflection seismic acquisition shoot and wondering what the best way was to extract UTM's (or latitude and longitude) and depth. I am reading through the headers and trying to make the best of it, but I am having a hard time making sense of it.

Comment: Hello, your question is currently too broad. Can you edit it to make the question more specific, like what exactly have you tried and what is the problem that you encounter? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy to spot the lat and lon coordinates. Have you found the spec? http://www.seg.org/documents/10161/77915/ukooa_p1_90.pdf